# Cannot boot into Grub2 menu (dual-boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10)

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, ubuntu-16.04

I have a an HP envy dv6 notebook on which was installed Windows 8 (later on upgraded to Windows 10). I have installed ***Ubuntu 16.04*** on my laptop in ***dual-boot*** mode with ***Windows 10***. I have struggled to get the GRUB menu to launch on boot, from which I could get to choose either Ubuntu 16.04 or Windows 10. The problem is that I directly boot into Windows 10, without having the chance to access the GRUB menu. Anyway I tried certain things:

1. Turning off the "***fast-startup***" spec in Windows 10.
2. Turning off the "***secure boot***" feature in my UEFI firmware
3. I used "***boot-repair***" in Ubuntu (by booting into the GRUB through choosing it from the UEFI boot options ***F11***) and tried the suggestions I got from the tool. Nothing changed.
4. I tried changing the boot order using the "efibootmgr" tool in Ubuntu while using the -o option to create a new boot order, but without any success: the boot order changes in the Ubuntu session, but when I restart my laptop I end up on Windows 10 without passing through GRUB2
5. I tried changing the boot order as an administrator in the Windows command line by typing: `bcdedit set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and `bcdedit set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`
6. I tried using the "easyUEFI" tool in Windows 10, only to discover that the Ubuntu entry does not appear in the list of boot entries in the tool (even though I saw it in the list of boot entries in the boot menu using ***F11***)
7. I also need to mention that my boot menu entry list is a bit of a mess now; I tried to clean it using `sudo update-grub2` but nothing changed, so if there is a way to clean it up, thanks upfront for sharing.

The only way I was able to go into the GRUB menu is by restarting after Windows has launched while holding down the <**shift**> key and ending up on the BIOS menu from which I got to the UEFI firmware settings and chose the Ubuntu entry.

Here's what I got using "***efibootmgr***" in the Ubuntu terminal:

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 3000,3001,3002,3003,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0002* Ubuntu
Boot0003* Ubuntu
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot3000* EFI Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3001* EFI Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3002* EFI Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3003* EFI Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```

The last snippet of what I got in the "***boot-repair***" log:

```
Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda (1000GB) disk!

The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your BIOS.
If your BIOS does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

P.S. I still have two photos to share (one for the easyUEFI tool under Windows 10, and another one for the boot order list in the UEFI menu) and that I couldn't post because I don't have enough reputation points. But maybe I'll be capable of posting them while interacting with you later.